# Refactoring if statements for DTO

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns, refactoring

I have too many `if` statements and I want to refactor my code. I receive an object from an another API which contains a list of objects with key value pairs.

Here is an example of the JSON:

```json
{
    "document": {
        "documentfields": {
            "documentfield": [{
                    "name": "number",
                    "value": "201656591"
                },
                {
                    "name": "name",
                    "value": "test document"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to map the object `Document` to a `DTO` class.

The DTO class looks like this:

```java
@Data
public class DocumentDto {

    private String name
    private String link;
    private String type;
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;
    //and a lot of variables...
}
```

Currently, my code looks like this:

```java
FooDto fooDto = new FooDto();
source.getObjects()
    .stream()
    .forEach(object -> {
        if (object.getName().equals("foo1")) {
            fooDto.setFoo(object.getValue());
        }
        if (object.getName().equals("foo2")) {
            fooDto.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(object.getValue()));
        }
        //and a lot of if statements...
    });
```

The `if` statements contain string to string mapping. But also string to `int` and string to `LocalDateTime`.

How can I refactor this with a design pattern?

Comment: It seems, the purpose of this code needs to be clarified first.  _Why_ a single `fooDto` is created and then in the stream, some fields are initialized due to some rules, and all the changes are applied to the same DTO?  Perhaps it's worth to filter matching object(s) and then map the `object` to `FooDto`.  However, the entire question lacks clarity.

Comment: @AlexRudenko I have edited my question. I hope the question is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `documentType` is in reference to as it doesn't seem to be declared anywhere, but would you consider a case switch statement?

```
switch("foo2") {
  case object.getName():
    fooDto.setFoo(object.getValue());
    break;
  case documentType.getNaam():
    fooDto.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(object.getValue()));
    break;
  default:
    // default
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question. But this not the way I'm looking for.

Comment: Could you use object.getName() in the first line of the switch statement, is that the thing always been compared against?